# Any way to set background-size with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set backgroundSize with jQuery, using the code below,  and I keep getting an error on the fourth line down: "unexpected identifier."

```
    bigwidth  = 200;  
    bigheight = 100; 
    $(e.target).css({backgroundImage: 'url(' + src + ')',
                     backgroundSize : bigwidth bigheight
                });
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `backgroundSize: bigwidth + ' ' + bigheight`

You need to specify the space between parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong ... it should work like this (notice  `bigwidth +' '+ bigheight`) :

```
bigwidth  = 200;  
bigheight = 100; 
$(e.target).css({backgroundImage: 'url(' + src + ')',
                 backgroundSize : bigwidth +' '+ bigheight
            });
```